# How to print product of all inputted numbers using a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, integer

```
int main() {

    cout << "Enter some numbers fam! " << endl;
    cout << "If you wanna quit, just press q" << endl;
    
    int n{ 0 };
    int product = 1;
    char quit = 'q';


    while (n != 'q') {

        cin >> n;
        product = product* n;
        cout <<"The product is : " << product << endl;

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << product;




    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I print it out and cut the code using 'q', it prints me an infinite amount of "The product is 0". Also, how can I print out the final product of all numbers at the end?

Comment: You forget-ted to take the input.

Comment: The only way `n` will ever be equal to `'q'` is if the user enters 113. Pressing "q"` will cause the input to fail, and since you aren't checking if it succeeded you have an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are some problems in your code.

First, you are taking input and assigning it to an int, which might not have been a problem, but you are also comparing the int to a char(which will cause problems in your case)

```
int n{ 0 };

while(n != 'q') {
    cin >> n;
}
```

To solve that, you can make the `n` a string and then convert it into an integer with `stoi(n)` to use with the calculation

```
string n; // don't need to initialize a string, they are initialized by default.
int product = 1;

cin >> n; // Taking input before comparing the results
while(n != "q") { // Had to make q a string to be able to compare with n
    product *= stoi(n); // Short for product = product * stoi(n)
    cout <<"The product is : " << product << endl;
    cin >> n; // Taking input for the next loop round
}

cout << endl;
cout << product;
```

Comment: Awesome!!! it worked thank you!!!